# need help to solve dependncy error

Tags: java, android

I'm learning app development using android studio.

On build.gradle page i got stuck with one error i.e

> "compile'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'"

under dependencies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do what it says... You need to use `25.2.0`, not `23.0.0`

This is especially needed because your `compileSdk 25` should be using version 25 support library.

Comment: i tried that as well but the red line is still there

Comment: Then there is probably a different error message you are not showing us, because this is the answer to resolve the message above

Comment: no i'm not hiding anything. there is no other error. all the code is correct. there were three errors in the beginnig one is the buildToolsVersion must be 25 or more than that. I changed that to 25 and that resolved. second one is on line "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'". I googled the solution and change it with force = true and got rid of the error. and the third error is what is asking above. I googled about that and changed versions but its still there.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest using the latest version of all related libraries. For example, `:9.2.0` Google play services are  several years old. Also, I personally find that most `parse.com` use cases have moved to Firebase